# Why vs code didn't recognize php file

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

When I open ***php file*** in VScode the **php** logo do not appear and the *script* look like VScode didn't recognize it.
With **html** and **css** and **js** and **C** files *Vscode* recognize them but with **php** doesn't work.

[image]

Any solution please

i can  do nothing

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Comment: Did you select the PHP language in the status bar (the one on the bottom)?

Comment: why do you open and close a string with different delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Save the file, close and open again VS Code
2. Check if the language detected by VS Code in the status bar (the one on the bottom) on the left is PHP, otherwise you'll see another language, in your case probably is “Pain Text”, as there are no linting at all.

[image: Vs Code status bar]